# Returning Value of a Promise - { AsyncStorage } React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to figure out how to return the result of a promise. I have been following the React Native documentation AsyncStorage page here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage

I'm making use of a code snippet provided in the documentation and made a couple of my own alterations to try and access the data.

As you can see in the example I provide I try to declare an empty array and populate it with the result of the AsyncStorage call.

```
export const loadLocalData = async () => {
var itemsStoredLocally = [];

        AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {
        AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (err, stores) => {
            stores.map((result, i, store) => {
                let key = store[i][0];
                let value = store[i][1];

                console.log("Inside the method : ", result)
                itemsStoredLocally.push(result);
            });
        });
    })

    console.log("Outside the method: ", itemsStoredLocally);

   return itemsStoredLocally;
}
```

In my console I am getting this:

```
Outside the method:  Array []
Inside the method :  Array [
  "1234",
  "The data stored locally",
]
```

When really what I want to see is this:

```
Inside the method :  Array [
  "1234",
  "The data stored locally",
]

Outside the method:  Array [
  "1234",
  "The data stored locally",
]
```

From what I understand a promise is being returned and I need to handle that promise in a way that I can wait for it to resolve AND then I can make use of it.

The trouble is, I just don't understand how. I see online there is mentions of things like Promise.resolve() and then making use a .then() method but everything that I try just doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the callback arguments. That is for when you *don't* use the promise return value, and that would just make the coder's life more difficult. Instead, omit those callback arguments, and rely on the returned promise:

```
export const loadLocalData = async () => {
    var itemsStoredLocally = [];

    // Use await:    
    const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
    const stores = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
    // Use forEach, not map: map is to return a mapped array
    stores.forEach(result => {
        let [key, value] = result;
        // Do something with key/value?
        // ...
        console.log("Inside the method : ", result)
    });
    return stores; // Just return the result
}
```

The function returns a promise, so you need to await it, for example with `then`:

```
loadLocalData.then(data => console.log("Outside the method: ", data));
```

Note that using `async` only makes sense when you use `await` in that function. So there was already a red flag there in your code...

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, really simple explanation and made the implementation seem much easier than what I found online. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
export const loadLocalData = async () => {
var itemsStoredLocally = [];

        AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {
        AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (err, stores) => {
            stores.map((result, i, store) => {
                let key = store[i][0];
                let value = store[i][1];

                console.log("Inside the method : ", result)
                itemsStoredLocally.push(result);
            });
            console.log("Outside the method: ", itemsStoredLocally);
            return itemsStoredLocally;
        });
    })
}
```